# How to make a record in an array of data selected by default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've certain records populated from json data as below

```
const data = [
    { country: { id: 1, cntryShortName: "USA", corpName: "USA Brad", status: "" } },
    { country: { id: 2, cntryShortName: "USA", corpName: "USA Bayker", status: ""} },
    { country: { id: 3, cntryShortName: "CAN", corpName: "Canada Zyphus", status: "" } },
    { country: { id: 4, cntryShortName: "USA", corpName: "USA Hamilton", status: "" } },
    { country: { id: 5, cntryShortName: "CAN", corpName: "Canada Sterling", status: "" } },
    { country: { id: 6, cntryShortName: "CAN", corpName: "Canada Stones", status: "" } },
    { country: { id: 7, cntryShortName: "USA", corpName: "USA Global Exchange", status: "" }},
    { country: { id: 8, cntryShortName: "USA", corpName: "USA Wrights", status: "" } },
    { country: { id: 9, cntryShortName: "GERMANY", corpName: "German Moto", status: "" } },
    { country: { id: 10, cntryShortName: "GERMANY", corpName: "German Wines", status: "" }},
    {country: {id: 11, cntryShortName: "GERMANY", corpName: "German Plastics", status: ""}},
    {country: { id: 12, cntryShortName: "CAN", corpName: "Canada Electronics", status: "" }}
  ];
```

My intention is that I want to keep record no 5 with data as `cntryShortName: "CAN", corpName: "Canada Sterling"`  keep selected by default

I have written the following code to make it active

```
const [busiData, setBusiData] = useState(data);

const getDefaultId = () => {
const newState = busiData.map(obj => {
      obj.status = "";
      if (obj.id === 5){
        return {...obj, status: "active"}
      }
      return (obj)
    })

    setBusiData(newState);
}

useEffect(() => {
    getDefaultId()
}, [])
```

As you can see from above code I'm trying to hard code the value and making that 5th record select by default but, no output. Any possible solution highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You forgot that you have `country` attribute as root key on each element inside array, do like this:

```
 const getDefaultId = () => {
        const newState = busiData.map(obj => ({...obj, country: { ...obj.country, status: obj.country.id === 5 ? "active" : ""}}))  
    
        setBusiData(newState);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot the `country` key part in you array

you can try something like this

```
const [busiData, setBusiData] = useState(data.map(d => d.country));

const getDefaultId = () => {
const newState = busiData.map(obj =>  obj.id === 5 ?
        {...obj, status: "active"}: {...obj, status: ''}
    )

    setBusiData(newState);
}

useEffect(() => {
    getDefaultId()
}, [])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't find `id` correctly, as you can see in your `json` row that you have a country object and then you have `id` So you access `id` directly instead access the country object, you can see the below code.

```
const [busiData, setBusiData] = useState(data);

const getDefaultId = () => {
const newState = busiData.map((obj, index) => {
      obj.country.status = "";
      if (obj.country.id === 5){
        busiData[index].country.status = "active"
      }
      return (obj)
    })

    setBusiData(newState);
}

useEffect(() => {
    getDefaultId()
}, [])
```